# I'm getting (ArgumentError) argument error trying to use elixir/erlang ets

Tags: erlang, elixir, ets

I'm trying to use the library to create a websocket client

[websockex](https://github.com/Azolo/websockex) along with **ets**

as I'm also using websocket in phoenix because I'm making an application of the type

```
client --websocket-->phoenix-->websocket-->third-party server
```

my intention is to save the socket object of each client together with a uid, so that when I get a response from a third-party server I know which client connected to my phoenix application I must send the message to, to save these sockets I use ets...

the problem is that every time I try to write to the table I get

```
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    (stdlib) :ets.insert(:sockets, {"uid", "mierda"})
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:680: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (iex) lib/iex/evaluator.ex:257: IEx.Evaluator.handle_eval/5
    (iex) lib/iex/evaluator.ex:237: IEx.Evaluator.do_eval/3
    (iex) lib/iex/evaluator.ex:215: IEx.Evaluator.eval/3
    (iex) lib/iex/evaluator.ex:103: IEx.Evaluator.loop/1
    (iex) lib/iex/evaluator.ex:27: IEx.Evaluator.init/4
    (websocketsample) lib/websocketsample_web/channels/websocket_communicator.ex:29: WebsocketCommunicator.translate/3
    (websocketsample) lib/websocketsample_web/channels/timer_channel.ex:15: WebsocketsampleWeb.TimerChannel.handle_in/3
    (phoenix) lib/phoenix/channel/server.ex:268: anonymous fn/4 in Phoenix.Channel.Server.handle_info/2 
    (websocketsample) lib/websocketsample_web/endpoint.ex:1: WebsocketsampleWeb.Endpoint.instrument/4
    (stdlib) gen_server.erl:637: :gen_server.try_dispatch/4
    (stdlib) gen_server.erl:711: :gen_server.handle_msg/6
```

to make a test, inside start_link I tried to save a value and immediately receive it...this works without problems, however inside my translate function, if I try to write to the table, I get the above mentioned error...

I even tried using IEx.pry and in that context to make a save any (to validate that the problem is effectively with this and is not a problem with my function) I could not effectively save the value

```
defmodule WebsocketCommunicator do
  use WebSockex
  require Logger
  require IEx

  def start_link(opt \\ []) do
    Logger.info("inicializando la tabla")
    :ets.new(:sockets,[:named_table,:public])
    :ets.insert(:sockets, {"test","this works"})
    [{_k,v}] = :ets.lookup(:sockets,"test")  #this works ok
    Logger.info("valor es #{v}" )


WebSockex.start_link("ws://localhost:8999",__MODULE__,:fake_state,opt)
  end


  def translate(client,message,socket) do
    uid = Ecto.UUID.generate()
    IEx.pry()
    :ets.insert(:sockets,{uid,socket}) #this fails
    #inside pry if I type this also fails
    :ets.insert(:sockets,{"something","boom"})
    [{_k,v}] = :ets.lookup(:sockets,uid)
    Logger.info("valor es #{v}" )
    #mensaje = Poison.encode!(%{"uid" => uid, "text"=>message})

    WebSockex.send_frame(client, {:text, "doesnt works!!!"})
  end

  def handle_frame({:text,msg},:fake_state) do
    Logger.info("receiving --> #{msg}")
    {:ok, :fake_state}
    # {:reply,{:text,msg},:fake_state}
  end
end
```

websockex is not using genserver so I can't use an init function, do you know which could be the issue here or give me some workaround?...thank you so much...

Comment: Did the process that created the table end by the time `translate()` was called?  *[A table] is not automatically destroyed unless the owner process terminates...The default owner is the process that created the table.*

Comment: thanks for the reply @7stud nope, WebsocketCommunicator start the ets and it's running all the time, I've upload the project to https://github.com/cocodrino/phoenix-error-ets

it's a bit messy but the important files are 
https://github.com/cocodrino/phoenix-error-ets/blob/master/lib/websocketsample_web/channels/timer_channel.ex

https://github.com/cocodrino/phoenix-error-ets/blob/master/lib/websocketsample_web/channels/websocket_communicator.ex

thank you...